# TypeLoadException Using VB.net Assembly in ASP.net Core 2 API

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm trying to transition a legacy ASP.net VB Webforms project into a ASP.net Core 2 API project.

Unfortunately, there are quite a lot of references to an Assembly that was written in VB.net and I don't have access to the original code.
I can add the reference to the project, but when I try and debug the project, it runs until I use a method from the assembly and I get the error:

```
TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateAndTime' from assembly 'Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=10.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
```

There are a number of variables that are passed to it, one of which is a DateTime.

```
DateTime dateIn = new DateTime(2018, 5, 7);
DateTime dateOut = new DateTime(2018, 5, 20);
```

I have spun up a simple C# Web forms project, added the assembly and referenced the code in the same way and it works and returns the correct value, it just doesn't like the .net core 2 environment.

I have found other similar questions, but the answers don't seem to relate:
[System.TypeLoadException Microsoft.VisualBasic ASP.NET Core 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47996708/system-typeloadexception-microsoft-visualbasic-asp-net-core-2)

Ideas of where to start?

**Update 1**

Thanks for the comments to clearing up exactly how this should work.
I've looked at the Tools mentioned by @john to converting the code from the DLL back into some form of source. Unfortunately, I don't currently possess the required time (or probably the skills) to rewrite the large chunks of code that aren't working.

**New Question/Idea**:
Is there someway I can compile out the current DLL as some sort of exe or com object, and interact with it outside of the .NET Core layer, and just on an OS layer? (Hopefully, I'm explaining that correctly. I realise that this will break the cross-platform compatibility, but it might solve the problem in the short term, to help get the project out the door and then time can be devoted to rewriting the problem assembly.)

Comment: Are you saying that you're trying to reference a .NET Framework assembly from .NET Core code? You shouldn't be doing that.

Comment: So it's an ASP.NET Core project, but is it targeting .NET Core or .NET Framework, because it could be either. If it's .NET Core then nothing from the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace that is basically a holdover from VB6 will be available because it's not .NET Standard-compliant. In that case, you're going to need to replace that DLL with a .NET Core version that doesn't call out to those legacy functions. Whether it's OK to use them has been a bone of contention for years and here's an example of why it's not. They may not bite you often, but once is still too often.

Comment: There's always this, but you'd have to still recompile that Dll somehow I think. Not all methods are available in it so you may be out of luck. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualBasic/10.3.0-rc1

Comment: @john - I believe that is what I'm doing. I wasn't aware of this .dll assembly until I had already begun down the path of .NET Core.

Is there a way to convert it, my reading suggests I need to work out how to convert it to .Net Standard? All I have is this dll with some business logic in it, no access to the source code of it. Can I create some sort of wrapper and compile it out to use .Net Core / .Net Standard?

Comment: @Charlie .NET Standard is intended for cross-platform code (class libraries) that can be referenced from .NET Core and .NET Framework projects alike. .NET Core is meant for cross-platform projects. It's unlikely you could wrap this library up as doing so would require you to reference it, and would prevent your code being cross-platform. Is there any way you can reverse engineer it (if licenses allow) and place the relevant code into a .NET Core or .NET Standard project?

Comment: @john - It was developed internally years ago, so I can probably attempt to reverse engineer it - licensing isn't an issue. Just getting the logic correct is the tricky part. The aim of the project is to rewrite the Web Forms application, that is tightly coupled to windows, into something that is a bit more flexible & agile, based around a REST api, that one day might be deployed on a Linux box. Maybe I should start looking at Mono in detail.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 - I've added it with Nuget, although it doesn't appear to support DateTime Type - althought your comment might be handy for someone else in the future.

Comment: @Charlie Tools like RedGate's .NET Reflector or JetBrains' DotPeek should be able to convert the library into source code for you. They're not perfect though, so no guarantees everything will work.

Answer (score 0):

*A note to those who come across this post in the future.*

For the time being, I have wrapped the VB.Net assembly in a basic WCF service.
Given that this assembly is a 'black box' where it has queries thrown at it and it returns an answer, it lends itself to working in a WCF service.

I would assume that this solution would not work for most people.

*Note: I'm yet to test this in production. - I'll provide an update when I do.*